# How to create a spin box in dm-script?

Tags: user-interface, dialog, dm-script

I would like to create a spin box on a modal/modeless dialog in dm-script, which enables users to increase or decrease the number value in the text field by clicking up or down arrow buttons (i.e., spin buttons).

Is there an appropriate way to create such a spin box? It will be appreciated if you share some wisdom. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> #### There exists no "spin control" for scripted dialogs.

However, you can build a proxy-spin control by creating and arranging according push-buttons. It is a bit crude, but the following code creates this:

[image]

```
Class CMySpin : UIFrame
{
    TagGroup CreateDLGTgs( object self )
    {
        TagGroup DLGtgs, DLGItems
        DLGtgs = DLGCreateDialog( "Test", DLGItems )
        TagGroup upButton = DLGCreatePushButton( "U", "OnPushUp" ).DLGExternalPadding(0,-5).DLGInternalPadding(-2,-3)
        TagGroup downButton = DLGCreatePushButton( "D", "OnPushDown" ).DLGInternalPadding(-2,-3)
        TagGroup field = DLGCreateIntegerField( 10, 10 ).DLGIdentifier( "field" )
        
        TagGroup SpinGroup = DLGGroupItems( upButton, downButton ).DLGTableLayout(1,2,0)
        TagGroup fieldWithSpin = DLGGroupItems( field, SpinGroup ).DLGTableLayout(2,1,0)
        DLGItems.DLGAddElement( fieldWithSpin )
        return DLGtgs
    }

    void OnPushUp( object self )
    {
        taggroup fieldTG = self.LookupElement( "field" )
        number value =  fieldTG.DLGGetValue()
        value++
        fieldTG.DLGValue( value )
    }
    
    void OnPushDown( object self )
    {
        taggroup fieldTG = self.LookupElement( "field" )
        number value =  fieldTG.DLGGetValue()
        value--
        fieldTG.DLGValue( value )
    }
    
    void CreateAndPose( object self )
    {
        self.Init( self.CreateDLGTgs() )
        self.Pose()
    }
}

Alloc(CMySpin).CreateAndPose()
```

You can then play with looks a bit by using bitmap buttons instead of simple push buttons and setting things up until they look more appealing.

f.e. I created this variant:

[image]

With this code:

```
Class CMySpin : UIFrame
{
    
    TagGroup CreateDLGTgs( object self )
    {
        image arrowImg := [7,5]:
                {   { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                    { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                    { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 },
                    { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
                    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } }


        number factor = 2
        image upArrow := RealImage("",4,factor*7,factor*5)
        upArrow=arrowImg.warp( icol / factor, irow / factor ) 
        image downArrow = upArrow
        downArrow.FlipVertical()
        
        rgbImage upArrowUp = RGB( upArrow * 100, upArrow * 100, upArrow * 100 )
        rgbImage upArrowDown = RGB( upArrow * 200, upArrow * 200, upArrow * 200 )
        rgbImage downArrowUp = RGB( downArrow * 100, downArrow * 100, downArrow * 100 )
        rgbImage downArrowDown = RGB( downArrow * 200, downArrow * 200, downArrow * 200 )
            
        TagGroup DLGtgs, DLGItems
        DLGtgs = DLGCreateDialog( "Test", DLGItems )
        TagGroup upButton = DLGCreateBevelButton( upArrowUp, upArrowDown, "OnPushUp" ).DLGExternalPadding(0,-3).DLGInternalPadding(-2,-3)
        TagGroup downButton = DLGCreateBevelButton( downArrowUp, downArrowDown, "OnPushDown" ).DLGExternalPadding(0,-3).DLGInternalPadding(-2,-3)
        TagGroup field = DLGCreateIntegerField( 10, 10 ).DLGIdentifier( "field" )
        
        TagGroup SpinGroup = DLGGroupItems( upButton, downButton ).DLGTableLayout(1,2,0)
        TagGroup fieldWithSpin = DLGGroupItems( field, SpinGroup ).DLGTableLayout(2,1,0)
        DLGItems.DLGAddElement( fieldWithSpin )
        
        return DLGtgs
    }

    void OnPushUp( object self )
    {
        taggroup fieldTG = self.LookupElement( "field" )
        number value =  fieldTG.DLGGetValue()
        value++
        fieldTG.DLGValue( value )
    }
    
    void OnPushDown( object self )
    {
        taggroup fieldTG = self.LookupElement( "field" )
        number value =  fieldTG.DLGGetValue()
        value--
        fieldTG.DLGValue( value )
    }
    
    void CreateAndPose( object self )
    {
        self.Init( self.CreateDLGTgs() )
        self.Pose()
    }
}

Alloc(CMySpin).CreateAndPose()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your  quick responce and showing example scripts. They are working quite well for my purpose. I really appreciate your advice. By the way, instead of pushing up/down buttons, can we increase or decreate the value by pressing up/down arrow keys when the field is active? If the implementation is not so difficult, I would like to implement this additionl function to my script.

Comment: @kachigusa This would be a separate question, but as a short answer: You can only do that if you attach a "keylistener" to an image-display and have such an image "front-most", or if you have some background-thread running script constantly checking for key-events. The second is not advised at all. The first is easy, but only useful for specific situations. You can, unfortunately, not have keylisteners on dialog elements.

Comment: I really appreciate your helpful advices in spite that my additional question should be a separate question. I was wondering about whether or not there are the keylisteners for dialog element in dm-script. Although the absence of such kinds of keylistners is unfortunate news for me, alternative ways you suggested are quite helpful ideas. Thank you very much.