# How to create a slider in GMS3

Tags: dm-script

I would like to create a slider dialog in dm-script, which enables users to change the number value in the text field.

Is there an appropriate way to create such a spin slider? It will be appreciated if you share some wisdom. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Remember to share what you've tried/researched when asking for help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the dm-scripting community here.

Answer (score 0):

Scripted dialogs do currently not support sliders at all.
You could create "spin controls" by creating two arranged push-buttons and an edit field though.

You may also want to look at this answer here on [spin controls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49077921/1302888)